# Actionhero worker (node) to run on different machine and one node is "Resque scheduler master", which assign task to remote workers

Tags: cluster-computing, actionhero

I have made (localhost:8080)

> scheduler: true

in one node to make it scheduler master.

Other node have schedule turned off (localhost:8000)

> scheduler: false

How will "scheduler master" assign task to other node..??

Answer (score 1):

I work this out. It was simple but simple is tough.

We just have to follow AH architecture.

First of all make sure AH is not using `fakeredis`.

Than server should not have nay `taskprocessor`

And all other worker should have one or more `taskprocessors`. You can find that in `/config/tasks.js`. Thn in `/config/tasks.js` name the queue in queue array on which worker should work.

Once they are sharing redis they will share tasks and start working on tasks in queue.